# Dividing a string to smaller strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I have a string which has 1000 characters. I want to split this string to an array of strings of 5 characters each. The code is:

```
int main()
{

    string myarray[200];
    int k = 0;
    string num = "a string with 1000 characters";

    while(!num.empty())
    {
        strncpy(myarray[k],num.c_str(),5);
        num.erase(0,5);
        k++;

    }

}
```

This code gives this error :

> cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'char*'
>   for argument '1' to 'char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)'|

I tried the code without .c_str(), the result was same.
How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `std::string::substr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) expect first argument is `char*` while you passed `string` to it. Compiler will complain that it can't convert `std::string` to `char*`:

```
char *strncpy( char *dest, const char *src, std::size_t count );
```

Better use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and call [std::string::substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string num("a string with 1000 characters");

std::vector<std::string> myarray;
myarray.reserve(200);

for (int i=0; i<num.size(); i+=5)
{
   myarray.push_back(num.substr(i, 5));    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`std::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string num = "a string with 1000 characters";
std::vector<std::string> myArray;

for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < num.length(); i += 5 )
{
    myArray.push_back( num.substr( i, 5 ) );
}
```

`std::vector` is a bit more flexible than `array`.

A [working live example](http://ideone.com/xKNcSe).

Answer (score 1):

You may use `std::substr` as:

```
string MyArray[200];
for int i = 0;i<1000;i+=5)
{
    MyArray[i] = num.substr(i,5);
}
```

And I would advice you to use `vector<string>` instead of `MyArray[200]` for a bit more flexibility.